# best practice to upload file to S3 and trigger a lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I would like to implement the following scenario using AWS S3 and Lambda.

User takes a photo from mobile, add description, location and more attributes as a separate metadata. Upload the image file to S3 with the metadata as the file inner metadata. According to [that](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html) link I can do it by adding a key value pair to ObjectMetadata with "x-amz-meta-" as a key.

I was managed to invoke the lambda every creation of a file in my S3 bucket but in the S3Event from the Lambda's invocation method I'm not getting the metadata that I putted in the ObjectMetadata.

Code sample for the upload process:

```
PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(BUCKET_NAME, KEY_NAME, file);
ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
metadata.addUserMetadata("x-amz-meta-xxxxx", "test123");
por.setMetadata(metadata);
s3client.putObject(por);
```

I hope that I provided enough information

Answer (score 1):

AWS recommends to store files on S3, files' metadata on the DynamoDB. With this approach easy and cost effective to perform a search by the metadata. Please keep in mind, that according to S3 pricing model you pay for each API call.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately this isn't answer my question. With your solution the client need to perform 2 Rest api calls while I'm seeking for a solution with only 1 api call - to s3 with the client metadata attached -> from there invocation of the lambda with the S3Event that should contain the metadata.

Comment: That is true. S3Event doesn't contains file metadata. You have to in the lambda to do a call GET (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html) or HEAD( http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html) methods to get a metadata.

Answer (score 0):

You can add metadata during the upload. I used the `upload_file` but `putObject` should work as well:

```
s3client.putobject(por, ExtraArgs={"Metadata":metadata})
```